# Issue Rendering Chartkick on 2nd render in Dialog Box

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, dialog, chartkick

I have the Chartkick gem installed in my app and everything works fine the first time i render the chart in a jquery dialog box:

[image]

But the second time i open a dialog box with the chart without reloading the page i get:

[image]

The way i get this to show is:

### Controller:

```
  def lanes_chart
       data = RejectLoads.group_by_week(:tend_date, week_start: :sat, range: 6.months.ago..Date.today).where(:edi_name => params["company"]).count
       options = {"library" => {"height" => "400px", "title" => "Company: #{params["company"]}}", "hAxis" => {"title" => "Weeks"}, "vAxis" => {"title" => "Count"}}}
     @data = data
     @options = options
  end
```

### Main View:

```
<div id="reject_chart_dialog" title="Reject Origin Chart">
  <div id="chart"></div>
</div>

<%= link_to_function  "Chart", "chart('#{o}')"%>
<script>
    function chart(state){
        /* code here */
        $.ajax({
            url: "/reports/lanes_chart",
            data: {
                chart_name: "state",
                state: state
            },
            type: "get",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#reject_chart_dialog").dialog("open");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

### lanes_chart.js.erb

```
$("#chart").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "reports/charts/chart_lanes", locals: {  data: @data, options: @options  }) %>");
```

### _chart_lanes.html.erb

(partial replacing chart div every time)

```
<div id="chart">
  <%= area_chart data, options %>
</div>
```

### application.js file

```
$( "#reject_chart_dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 1000,
    buttons: {
        Close: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
});
```

I have had a similar [issue to this rendering google maps in a dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218224/issue-rendering-google-maps-on-2nd-render-in-dialog-box) and was able to fix it by initializing the google maps on the open function of the dialog box like so:

```
$("#map_form").dialog({
    open: function( event, ui ) {
        initialize_map();
    },
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 1000,
    buttons: {
        "Close": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

I think i will have to do the same thing with Chartkick but not sure what to call.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this issue by calling a resize event every time i opened the dialog box

```
$( "#reject_chart_dialog" ).dialog({
    open: function() {
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
    },
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 1000,
    buttons: {
        Close: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
});
```

also added a little style on the chart div.

```
.chart-options {
    max-height: 300px;
    max-width: 950px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Had to add this to my dialog div because there was overflow and it scrolled.

```
#reject_chart_dialog {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

just to make it look a little better.